# c/c++ allocate on stack

Tags: c++, c, cpu-registers

I was reading [1) about stack pointers and the need of knowing both ebp (start of the stack for the function) and esp (end). The article said that you need to know both because the stack can grow, but I don't see how this can be possible in c/c++. (Im not talking about another function call because to my mind this would make the stack grow, do some stuff, then recursively be popped and back to state before call)

I have done a little bit of research and only saw people saying that `new` allocates on the heap. But the pointer will be a local variable, right ? And this is known at compile time and reserved in the stack at the time the function is called.

I started to think that maybe with loops you have an uncontrolled number of local variables

```
int a;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  int b = i + 3;
```

but no, this doesn't allocate n times `b`, and only 1 int is reserved just as it is for `a`.

So... any example ?

[1): http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames

Comment: All variables in C and C++ have existance in a *scope* context. Local non-static variables in a function, for example, are automatic only to that function. That said, what do you think the scope of existance is for `b` in your code?

Comment: There's nothing 'uncontrolled' in your example from a compiler's point of view.

Comment: Where does the article say "you need to know both because the stack can grow"? It only talks about parameters being passed on the stack.

Comment: Normally the size of stack at a given frame is fixed, however I've seen (in the ancient past) a function whose name I cannot recall that would allocate memory on the stack, by simply extending the size of the stack frame. This was much faster than, say, a malloc call, and it didn't have to be freed (in fact, it was impossible to) -- instead it was auto-released when the current stack frame terminated.

Comment: @mah You're thinking of `alloca` (sometimes prefixed with some underscores), and it's alive and kicking to this day.

Comment: @BrettHale   : yes I know the snippet I give is controlled, I was just giving an example that everything seemed controlled and impossible to have more local variables at running time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can allocate memory on the stack with `alloca` function from stdlib. I don't recommend to use this function in production code. It's to easy to corrupt your stack or get stack overflow.

Comment: C99 added support for variable length arrays which are also allocated this way.  `int foo(unsigned sz) { char bar[sz]; ...`

Answer (score 1):

The use of EBP is more for convenience. It is possible to just use ESP. The problem with that is, as parameters to functions are pushed onto the stack, the address relative to ESP of all the variables and parameters changes.

By setting EBP to a fixed, known position on the stack, usually between the function parameters and the local variables, the address of all these elements remains constant relative to EBP throughout the lifetime of the function. It can also help with debugging, as the value of ESP at the end of the function should equal the value of EBP.

The only way I know of to grow the stack in an indeterminate way at compile time, is to use alloca repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is indeed allocated on the stack. And the size is usually 4 or 8 bytes on 32 and 64bit architectures respectively. So you know the size of a pointer statically, at compile time, and you can keep them on the stack if you choose to do so.

This pointer can point to free store, and you can allocate memory to it dynamically - without having to know the size beforehand. Moreover, it is usually a good idea to keep stack frames empty, and compilers will even "enforce" this with (adjustable) limits. MSVC has 1MB if I recall correctly.

So no, there is no way you can create a stack frame of size that is unknown at compile time. Your stack frame of the code you posted will have room for 3 integers (a, b, i). (And possibly some padding, shadow space, etc, not relevant.) (It is TECHNICALLY possible to extend the size of stackframes at run time but you just don't want to do that almost never.)